# blender unable to start

Tags: startup-file

I have install [Blender 2.79b](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/) from the link in windows 7.
Installation was successfully installed, when i run blender exe, blender was unable to start, No error No warning, Nothing showing, Is there anyway to find with command prompt. May i know the reason why blender unable to start / launch. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

System Info
i5, 24GB RAM, 2GB Graphic Card, Win7